# Javascript countdown timer inside PHP while loop

Tags: javascript, php

I am selecting datetimes out of my database using PHP. For each date that is selected from the database I want to display the remaining H:D:M:S to the selected datetime using javascript. I do this by echoing the following javascript code inside the loop [while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))]:

```
<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("'.$formatted_date.'").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now an the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
document.getElementById("'.$counter.'").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("'.$counter.'").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```

I then echo the countdown timer using `<span id="'.$counter.'"></span>`
This works fine however every span value is the same regardless of the number of dates selected from the database. (I assume it is only calculating the countdown for the last value selected from the db instead of each value?)

Any help please?

Comment: You need an OOP countdown, but for now change `var x = setInterval(function() ` to `var x[<?= $counter; ?>] = setInterval(function()` and `clearInterval(x);` to `clearInterval(x[<?= $counter: ?>);` and have a `var x=[];` somewhere global - you likely need to change countDownDate  too

Comment: Are you echoing this entire script in your loop? That will not work at all, since the variables keep overwriting each other. It's also a grave violation of the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You need to rework your entire approach to this; ideally all your PHP loop does is echo an array of time values, then JS takes over building the countdowns based on the array of time values.

Comment: @rottenoats come on. That is completely unnecessary here. Just needs to make a proper OOP clountdown

Comment: @rottenoats Yeah, why get into AJAX when you can simply echo a basic DB output? Don't mix good advice with controversial "my eyes bleed" "advice".

Comment: @rottenoats `var times = <?= $times ?>;` seems fine to me; it's straightforward and not hard to read, so let's agree to disagree. And if there are PLENTY of alternative ways, why suggest AJAX and not something simpler?

Comment: @rottenoats I didn't realize OP was applying for a job. I thought he's asking how to do a few countdowns.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var ar, arLen, i, text, countDownDate, Date, x, now, distance, days, hours, minutes, seconds;
ar = <?php echo json_encode($testarray) ?>;
arLen = ar.length;
for (i = 0; i < arLen; i++) {

countDownDate = new Date(ar[i]).getTime();
x = setInterval(function() {
now = new Date().getTime();
distance = countDownDate - now;
text = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s";
document.getElementById([i]).innerHTML = text;
}, 1000);
}
</script>

Anyone know why this solution breaks as soon as I add x = setInterval(function() {